# Date Comparison in If condition in DB2

Tags: db2

I have two date parameters BeginDate and EndDate. I need to compare these two dates and then perform some sql select. For example, if BeginDate is lessthan or equal to EndDate, then only I need to query data. For example as below:

```
If @BeginDate <= @EndDate Then
   select statement1
   select statement2
...
End if
```

When I tried in DB2, I am getting an error.

Kindly suggest a sample with DB2 syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to do it simple, just add the condition to both select statements:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table_name> 
WHERE @BeginDate <= @EndDate;
```

Other solution would be using IF statement **within PL/SQL contexts** to execute SQL:

```
IF (@BeginDate <= @EndDate) THEN
  statements
END IF;
```

A more complete example for inline SQL PL, would be something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE_IF
(IN BeginDate DATE, IN EndDate DATE)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
  IF (BeginDate <= EndDate)
    THEN 
      statement1;
      statement2;
  END IF;
END!
```

Hope it's useful!

Comment: you should explain a bit more about how and why this works to make this a better answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My question is to compare dates in If condition and then execute some set of select statements. Can you please provide an example with if condition specific to Db2 syntax.

Comment: Hi Academia, When I use below syntax, like 
IF (@BeginDate <= @EndDate) THEN

Comment: An Unexpected token "IF (@BeginDate <= @EndDate) THEN" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT". Expected token may include "<space>".
This is the error message.

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder
------------------------------

An error occurred while executing the query.
[DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "IF (@BeginDate <= @EndDate) THEN" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

[DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "IF (@BeginDate <= @EndDate) THEN" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601 (IBM OLE DB Provider for DB2)

Comment: Hi, I am using IF statement in Inline SQL. The main purpose of using this IF statement in my Inline SQL is, to prevent running the sql statement if the condition in if statement fails. Is this possible in Inline SQL?

Comment: No, I am not creating a stored procedure. I am creating an In-line sql in Report Builder with DB2 as datasource. So Inline SQL does not allow use of If statement? If so, can you please let me know any other ways to achieve the same requirement.

Comment: You are using inline SQL PL. And yes, you can use if statement since it is PL. Just check the [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0009220.html) I gave you before. It is well explained. The problem you have I guess is due to the termination character. Also, add Begin Atomic since it is an Inline Compound statement.